# Shortcut based on filetype

Tags: vimrc

I would like to do the following remap:

```
:inoremap <Option-Space> &nbsp;
```

In other words, pressing option-space would add an html-escaped space. How could this be done, so that it only works when `ft=html` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set shortcut based on filetype with autocmd mapping:

```
autocmd FileType html inoremap <buffer> <F5> &nbsp;
autocmd FileType c inoremap <buffer> <F5> Hello, C!
```

So in HTML files `<F5>` would type `&nbsp;` and in C files it would type `Hello, C!`

Probably your vimrc setting should be following:

```
autocmd FileType html inoremap <buffer> <Option-Space> &nbsp;
```

See more in help:

```
:h autocmd
:h :map-<buffer>
```

Comment: autocommand should always be defined within a group to permit reloading of the file where they are defined. Beside, the ft-specific mappings shall also be `:map-<buffer>`.

Comment: I disagree with this. File type local shortcuts are meant to be mapped via `localmapleader`. It is optimized for these purposes.

Comment: @justahuman. `<localleader>` is just another global leader key. A non buffer restricted mapping will still be global, even with a `<localleader>`. Open two buffers, define `:nnoremap <localleader>A :echo "foo"<cr>` in one buffer, go to the other buffer, and trigger the mapping. You'll see that it will also exist: the mapping is global. ft-related mappings shall be defined with `<buffer>`.

Comment: @LucHermitte would a better approach here be using `autocmd FileType html inoremap <buffer> <Option-Space> &nbsp;` to use the `<buffer>` word so its local?

Comment: @David542, it's more that just _better_, it's _correct_. See my other answer with the exercise with abbreviations: without `<buffer>`, it's quickly a mess as abbreviations keep being overridden and in the end the wrong ft1 definition is applied in ft2 buffers.

Comment: @LucHermitte. Thanks for correction, did not know about <buffer> parameter in :map command. Edited answer, please check if it is correct now.

Comment: @Dmitry. Yes, it's much better, and correct :) The last thing is that it's better to put autocommands in a group: this permits to reload the file where they are defined without triggering multiple times the same autocommand. I don't know why _teaching_ resources show this flawed approach first without at least showing a proper way to do it, like here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/wiki/where_to_put_filetype_specific_stuff

Answer (score 1):

autocommands are a possible first step. In all cases they won't be enough (to restrict the mapping to the right filetype). And they don't really scale, that's why I recommend ftplugins instead.

Add a ftplugin in `~/.vim/ftplugin/{ftname}.vim` (don't forget `:filetype plugin on` in your `.vimrc`).

Then, in this ftplugin declare a buffer local mapping (`:h :map-<buffer>`). The `<buffer>` part is important, otherwise every time you open a buffer of a different filetype, the setting could be overridden (and possibly lost...) as it would be a *global* one.

```
:inoremap <buffer> <Option-Space> &nbsp;
```

Comment: I see. So basically, if I open a `python` file after an html file it will still have the option-space mapping in there, or what do you mean it's a global one?

Comment: Without `<buffer>`, if you open a python file after an html one, either you'll see `<option-space>` from html still working, or you'll override `<option-space>` with a new one (if you have another mapping dedicated to python), even in the previous html buffer. Without `<buffer>`, mappings and abbreviations are global: shared between all buffers.

Comment: I’ve had better experience with `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` (I think to make sure I don’t prevent the distribution ftplugins  from running, and to override plugin ftplugins where necessary)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. Good point. I'll have to check my config some day. And to check whether in `:runtime! {ft}*.vim {ft}/*.vim` files are sourced sorted by files (specified by `:runtime` order) or by directory (specified by `&rtp`).