# Need for 'buffer' when setting FileType

Tags: buffers

What would be the difference between these two commands?

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>d ihello!
```

And:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <localleader>d ihello!
```

One references `<buffer>` and one does not. To me they act the same in my testing of the two in different splits and then different windows, so was wondering why `<buffer>` needed to be included at all, but perhaps I'm not understanding why it's really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already answered this question you've asked two days ago [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25812/shortcut-based-on-filetype/25815#comment45645_25815)

> Without `<buffer>`, if you open a python file after an html one, either you'll see `<option-space>` from html still working, or you'll override `<option-space>` with a new one (if you have another mapping dedicated to python), even in the previous html buffer. Without `<buffer>`, mappings and abbreviations are global: shared between all buffers

To fully appreciate what happens, try the following

```
autocmd FileType python iab for for :<left>
autocmd FileType vim    iab for for<cr>endfor<up>
```

And then,

```
" open a python buffer
e foo.py
" type for + space
" -> should be ok

" open a vim buffer
sp foo.vim
" type for + space
" -> should be OK

" go back to the python buffer
sb foo.py " sb != sp
" type for + space
" -> you should see the vimscript snippet instead of the python one

" open a new python buffer
sp bar.py
" type for + space
" -> it works again!

" if you go back to foo.vim, 
sb foo.vim " sb != sp
" -> this time, this is the python snippet..
```

Non-`<buffer>` definitions are global, and `Filetype` event is triggered once per buffer.

**=> the right way to do it is to use buffer-specific mappings, abbreviations, commands, variables... for things that are specific to a filetype.**

And last thing, these things are not defined at a semantic level: while the even is `Filetype`, the definition is buffer-related, not filetype-related, as seen in this other Q/A of yours https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25865/626.

Comment: thanks for this, that's a great answer. I appreciate your time writing it up!

Comment: Here is going through your exercise with both global (right) and using `<buffer>` (left) -- https://imgur.com/a/VIkPgYI